# How can set link to desktop icon in extjs desktop?

Tags: extjs, desktop

I want to link another page in extjs desktop icon. in below image i want to user click to the "click to go google.com" icon and then user direct to google.com page.

[image]

How can I do?

Comment: click: function () { location.href = "google.com"; }

Comment: Infortuanetly don't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var googleWin = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
```